# Storage delete is not working laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have image file in `C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\storage\app\public\images\15201710351.jpg`

and i am trying to delete it from images folder with `Storage` class

```
$post = Post::find($id);
Storage::delete(storage_path().'app/public/images/'.$post->image);
```

and with

```
Storage::delete(storage_path('app/public/images/'.$post->image));
```

also with this

```
Storage::delete(public_path().'/storage/images/'.$post->image);// i have created symbolic link
```

there is no error message, but it is not working. i am using laravel 5.6, anyone can help?

Answer (score 10):

The default public storage location is `storage/app/public`, so just pass in the images directory and filename like so:

```
Storage::delete('images/' . $post->image)
```

Comment: The ```Storage::delete($path)``` only works with relative paths on the public desks its seems. I was perplexed by this also and now I've got it working.